# Null Pointer Exception while getting values from shared preference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

In my main activity I am trying to get the values stored in the shared preference,values are being stored in one of the fragement but when I run the application it gives me NPE,code where I am trying to get the values is:

```
 spref=new SharedPref(getApplicationContext());
        // get user data from session
          HashMap<String, Integer> selection = spref.GetPeerSelection();

            // name
   int selec = selection.get(SharedPref.KEY_SelectionId);
            // Save the Data in Database
           if(selec==1)
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if(selec==0)
                //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

My shared preference class is:

```
public class SharedPref {
    // Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences pref;
     Context _context;
     int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;
    // Editor for Shared preferences
    Editor editor;
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "Settings";

    // All Shared Preferences Keys


    // User name (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_MessageId = "msgid";
    public static final String KEY_SelectionId = "selectionid";
    // Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
 //   public static final String KEY_HOPCOUNT = "hopcount";
   // public static final String KEY_RANK = "rank";



    public SharedPref(Context context){
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);

        editor = pref.edit();
    }


  /*  public void SaveRank(int rank)

    {
         editor.putInt(KEY_RANK, rank);

    }

    */
    public void SaveSettings(String name){

        // Storing name in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_NAME, name);

       // editor.putInt(KEY_HOPCOUNT, HopCount);
       // commit changes
        editor.commit();
    }
  public void messageno(float msgno)

    {
         editor.putFloat(KEY_MessageId, msgno);

         editor.commit();
    }
  public void PeerSelection(int selection)

  {
     editor.putInt(KEY_SelectionId, selection);

     editor.commit();
  }

    public HashMap<String, String> getUserName(){
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // user name
        user.put(KEY_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_NAME, null));



        // return user
        return user;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Float> getMessageId(){
        HashMap<String, Float> id = new HashMap<String, Float>();
        // Message No
        id.put(KEY_MessageId, pref.getFloat(KEY_MessageId,0.0f) );



        // return user
        return id;
    }
    public HashMap<String, Integer> GetPeerSelection(){
        HashMap<String, Integer> selection = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        // Message No
        selection.put(KEY_SelectionId, pref.getInt(KEY_SelectionId,(Integer) null) );

        // return user
        return selection;
    }

}
```

My Log-cat is:

```
12-10 11:47:16.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6029): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-10 11:47:16.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6029): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{soft.b.peopleassist/soft.b.peopleassist.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-10 11:47:16.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-10 11:47:16.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2111)
12-10 11:47:16.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
12-10 11:47:16.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1251)
12-10 11:47:16.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-10 11:47:16.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-10 11:47:16.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4666)
12-10 11:47:16.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 11:47:16.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-10 11:47:16.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
12-10 11:47:16.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
12-10 11:47:16.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-10 11:47:16.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6029): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-10 11:47:16.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at soft.b.peopleassist.SharedPref.GetPeerSelection(SharedPref.java:98)
12-10 11:47:16.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at soft.b.peopleassist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:140)
12-10 11:47:16.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4510)
12-10 11:47:16.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
12-10 11:47:16.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2048)
12-10 11:47:16.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SharedPreference#getInt(String, int)` requires a primitive `int` as argument. When passing `null` as `Integer` it's **automatically unboxed**, but `null` is not a valid value for `int`, so that it throws a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

```
selection.put(KEY_SelectionId, pref.getInt(KEY_SelectionId,(Integer) null) );
```

You are putting null as default value..

Answer (score 1):

```
selection.put(KEY_SelectionId, pref.getInt(KEY_SelectionId,(Integer) null) );
```

Instead of returning a Null Integer, return 0 or -1 or any other number.

The error is due to the above code.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass `NULL` to the `getInt` method

Syntax of SharedPreferences.getInt

> public abstract int getInt (String key, int defValue)

it expect int (primitive data type) value , but you are passing `NULL` object, which does not supported

To illustrate the behavior in very simple manner,  below code will give you NPE

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        print((Integer)null);
    }
    public static void print(int i){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```